# open ir.actions.report in new window

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

as mentionned in the title, I need to open a report in a new window. I know that we can do so using `target` with act_window but I am stuck on how implement that to open a report.

```
<template id="myTemplate">
 <!--template-->
</template>

<report
    id="my_report_partner"
    string="Graphe"
    model="res.partner"
    report_type="qweb-html"
    file="myModule.myTemplate"
    name="myModule.myTemplate"
/>
```

button:

```
<button name="%(myModule.my_report_partner)d" type='action' string="open graph"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It could help you to archive your task.

```
return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
        'target': 'new',
        'url': '/report/html/%s/%s?enable_editor' % ('event.event_event_report_template_badge', self.id),
    }
```

Comment: well it works, but it's just opening in a new tab not a new window and I am missing the print button

Comment: There is no way to open it in new window( as I have not seen in odoo) and you can add " ? download=true" to print the report

Comment: you mean in the url? doesn't work..nothing changers